# consistent sql notation TRUE/FALSE

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2012

I am using delphi xe 5 with the "new" FireDac-Components and currently I am searching for a consistent notation for TRUE and FALSE in SQL as I want to connect to several databases with the same code.

Currently I am using the Advantage Database Server an with this it is allowed to write something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM COMPANY 
WHERE IsActive = TRUE;
```

With MS-SQL it is not allowed to write TRUE/FALSE and I have to use 1/0 instead. 
Does anyone have any experience by converting from one database to another database and had the same problems with the notation of sql-statments.

Furthermore there are other problems like the `GROUP BY`. The Advantage Database Server although allows to write GROUP BY 1,2,3,4 even the columns 1,2,3,4 are reprimands to other tables. 
So any help to this would be helpful, too!!

Thanks in advance, Maggi_MT

Comment: You can use the [`escape sequence`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_%28FireDAC%29#Escape_Sequences) like `...WHERE IsActive = {l True}`. They are designed just for this purpose. But I would prefer using parameter for that value. You'd get rid of this problem and as a benefit you'd get that value *controlled from outside*.

Comment: Postgres has true support for boolean datatype. So you can write `isActive = true` or even just `isActive` if that is a *real* `boolean` column. But I am not sure what you are actually asking. Your example is valid "*SQL*" (as in: standard SQL). So your "a consistent notation for `true`/`false` *in SQL* cannot be answered, as that _is_ already "*SQL". It's just that not all DBMS comply with the SQL standard in the same way.

Comment: @a_horse, that's why there are escape sequences in FireDAC library (client library that the OP uses). It allows you to write commands in a unified syntax for all supported DBMSs.

Comment: @TLama: then you should add that as an answer

Comment: Look at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the TRUE OR FALSE value within a single quotes like this 'TRUE'/'FALSE'.

or else try with the sample code.

DECLARE @company TABLE
  (
     id  INT,
     IsActive BIT
  )

INSERT INTO @company
VALUES      (1,
             0),
            (2,
             1)

SELECT *
FROM   @company
WHERE  IsActive IN ( '1', 'true' )

SELECT *
FROM   @company
WHERE  IsActive IN ( '0', 'false' )